# When closing as duplicate, searching for more questions after choosing a question initiates the close vote

Tags: bug, vote-to-close

**Reproduction:**

1. Go to any question
2. Click “close”
3. Choose “as a duplicate”
4. Select a question from the list
5. Start typing a new search term into the search/ID box
6. Hit ENTER before the debounced search callback is automatically triggered

**Expected:** Hitting ENTER explicitly triggers a search, and new search results appear
**Actual:** Hitting ENTER triggers the “Vote to close” action using the previously selected question

If you wait until the debounced search callback is triggered at least once, the “Vote to close” button is disabled again, but it should be disabled immediately when someone starts entering search terms into the search/ID box to prevent close votes accidentally getting the wrong target question.